# Get lambda parameters type into template argument pack

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, variadic-templates

I've been searching for an answer for hours, but I didn't find anything...
So, Here is my problem:

```
template<typename Signature> struct wrapper; // (1)

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct wrapper<Ret(Args...)> // (2)
{
  function static get(Ret(*fnc)(Args...), Args... args)
  {
    return function(/*some more stuff here that work*/);
  }
}
```

basically, this code extract the return type and the parameters of a function and return a generic function container. This code work with simple function.
But then I tried to use lambdas.
Without this wrapper (by handwriting the complete prototype) the code work, and I am able to call lambda.
But when I use this wrapper with lambda functions, I get some

> './some-file.cpp:xy:z: error: incomplete type 'wrapper >' used in nested name specifier'

Is the error caused by the two points (1) and (2) because a lambda could not fit into a function pointer ?
I am searching a way to get the arguments types of the lambda into a template argument pack (the return type is not important, all my lambdas does not return values (so it's void))
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: This is the full error message ;)

Comment: What version of what compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc (Gentoo 4.5.3-r2 p1.1, pie-0.4.7) 4.5.3
(and yes, lambda functions work)

Comment: I don't think variadic templates do though (not properly anyway)... You ought to try on GCC 4.7+.

Comment: yep.. but I had to build the project with GCC 4.5... I think I will create a special case for lambda (but they wouldn't take parameters, just capture the scope and wouldn't return anything)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you only *declare* the `wrapper` structure, you don't actually *define* it.

Try to properly define the structure:

```
template<typename Signature> struct wrapper {};
```

Comment: With this line, it just move the error. I get a ./x.cpp:x:x: error: 'get' is not a member of 'wrapper<main()::<lambda(int)>>' (this is the only line). It seems my specialisation does not match with a lambda function.